# Laravel Websockets Apache2 connection error on Production

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

In local all configuration working fine but on server it's throwing Internal Server Error

Following are configuration on production .conf file

```
   <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
        # Set this to the project's URL such as project1.cygnussolutions.com
        ServerName  laravelWebSockets.ls.codesorbit.net
        ServerAlias laravelWebSockets.ls.codesorbit.net
        ServerAdmin webmaster@codesorbit.co
        # Change the paths below to the project document root such as /var/www/$

        DocumentRoot /mnt/disk/www/laravelWebSockets.ls.codesorbit.net/public
        <Directory /mnt/disk/www/laravelWebSockets.ls.codesorbit.net/public>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
          Require all granted
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

        <FilesMatch \.php$>
          # For Apache version 2.4.10 and above, use SetHandler to run PHP as a fastCGI process server
          SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
        </FilesMatch>

        # Set Default Log Paths
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}supplierkeys_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/supplierkeys_access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
        RewriteRule .* wss://127.0.0.1:6001%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
        ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:6001
        ProxyPassReverse / ws://127.0.0.1:6001
        # Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
        # because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

        # RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =laravelWebSockets.ls.codesorbit.net
        # RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/laravelwebsockets.ls.codesorbit.net/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/laravelwebsockets.ls.codesorbit.net/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
     </VirtualHost>
   </IfModule>
```

Here is the broadcasting.php

```
   <?php

       return [
'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

'connections' => [

    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'encrypted' => true,
            'port' => 6001,
            'scheme' => 'https',
            'curl_options' => [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            ]
        ],
    ],

    

],

];
```

Here is websockets.php

```
  <?php

    use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Dashboard\Http\Middleware\Authorize;

    return [

      'dashboard' => [
         'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 443),
      ],

      'apps' => [
        [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'enable_client_messages' => true,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
        'encrypted' => true,
        'host' => env('WEBSOCKETS_URL') // for dashboard
    ],
],


'allowed_origins' => [
    parse_url(env('APP_URL'))['host']
],


'statistics' => [
    'perform_dns_lookup' => true,
],

];
```

Here is bootstrap.js

```
    window.Echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: 'pusher',
      key: window["MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY"], // <- from .env
      wsHost: window["WEBSOCKETS_URL"], // <- from .env
      wsPort: 80,
      wssPort: 443,
      disableStats: true, 
      enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
    });
```

This is all configured on a production but it's throwing Internal Server Error, the issue seems to be a
ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:6001
ProxyPassReverse / ws://127.0.0.1:6001
i have also enabled the proxy but nothing works. Any help would be great

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, have you tried to console.log window["WEBSOCKETS_URL"] ? window["MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY"]?

Comment: try to change bootstrap key and wsHost `MIX_WEBSOCKETS_URL` where in .env, `MIX_WEBSOCKETS_URL="${WEBSOCKETS_URL}"`